# Passing self as argument to a method decorator configurator

Tags: python, database, oop, python-decorators

I'm making an API using DRF with swagger UI documentation,
I want to make basic CRUD action as dynamic viewsets class so I can use class for another model,
but I have problem. I'm using @swagger_auto_schema and @action as decorator. Here example
for my get all data table:

```
#dynamic_crud.py
class DynamicCrud(viewsets.ViewSet):
    
    def __init__(self, serializer_class, model_class, table_name):
        self.serializer_class = serializer_class
        self.model_class = model_class
        self.table_name = table_name

    
    def api_response(self, message, status, data=None):
        return {'message': message, 'status': status, 'data': data}
    
#here is the problem
    @swagger_auto_schema(
        operation_summary=f'Get all {table_name}',
        responses={200: serializer_class(many=True)}
    )
    @action(detail=False, methods=['get'], url_path='getall', url_name=f'{table_name}_getall')
    def get_all(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            snippets = self.model_class.objects.filter(is_deleted=0)
            serializer = self.serializer_class(snippets, many=True)
            response_data = self.api_response(f'{self.table_name} retrieved successfully', 'success', serializer.data)
            return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
            response_data = self.api_response(str(e), 'error')
            return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

i put decorators inside class and decorators need references data. This class is parent and the data references is in child.

```
#views.py
table_data = [
    {
        'serializer_class': serializer.TblMCategories_serializer,
        'model_class': models.TblMCategories,
        'table_name': 'category'
    },    
    {
        'serializer_class': serializer.TblMProduct_serializer,
        'model_class': models.TblMProduct,
        'table_name': 'product'
    },
    # {
    #   rest of my table data...
    # }
]

class TblMCategories(dynamic_crud.DynamicCrud):

    def __init__(self):
        self.serializer_class = table_data[0]['serializer_class']
        self.model_class = table_data[0]['model_class']
        self.table_name = table_data[0]['table_name']
```

I know I can't use class self data in decorators since it not declared yet or self data is not available during code building. Is there any way or to get data in as self to put in decorators, or make my decorator have needed references data?

Answer (score 0):

Since `self` is only available when the decorated method is actually called, the trick here is to avoid decorating the method with `swagger_auto_schema` at class definition time, but rather decorate the method only when the method is called, which can be done by creating an ad-hoc decorator that returns a wrapper function to decorate the given method dynamically with `swagger_auto_schema` when the method is called, so that `swagger_auto_schema` can be passed with arguments derived from `self`.

Change:

```
@swagger_auto_schema(
    operation_summary=f'Get all {table_name}',
    responses={200: serializer_class(many=True)}
)
...
```

to:

```
@staticmethod
def _swagger_auto_schema_for_getall(method):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return swagger_auto_schema(
            operation_summary=f'Get all {self.table_name}',
            responses={200: serializer_class(many=True)}
        )(method)(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@_swagger_auto_schema_for_getall
...
```

or use a `lambda` function instead to avoid polluting the namespace with a method that is going to be used only once:

```
@(lambda method:
    lambda self, *args, **kwargs:
        swagger_auto_schema(
            operation_summary=f'Get all {self.table_name}',
            responses={200: serializer_class(many=True)}
        )(method)(self, *args, **kwargs)
)
...
```

Likewise for `action`:

Change:

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['get'], url_path='getall', url_name=f'{table_name}_getall')
...
```

to:

```
@staticmethod
def _action_for_getall(method):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return action(
            detail=False,
            methods=['get'],
            url_path='getall',
            url_name=f'{self.table_name}_getall'
        )(method)(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@_action_for_getall
...
```

or with `lambda`:

```
@(lambda method:
    lambda self, *args, **kwargs:
        action(
            detail=False,
            methods=['get'],
            url_path='getall',
            url_name=f'{self.table_name}_getall'
        )(method)(self, *args, **kwargs)
)
...
```

The end result is code that looks like this:

```
class DynamicCrud(viewsets.ViewSet):
    @staticmethod
    def _swagger_auto_schema_for_getall(method):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return swagger_auto_schema(
                operation_summary=f'Get all {self.table_name}',
                responses={200: serializer_class(many=True)}
            )(method)(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    @staticmethod
    def _action_for_getall(method):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return action(
                detail=False,
                methods=['get'],
                url_path='getall',
                url_name=f'{self.table_name}_getall'
            )(method)(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    @_swagger_auto_schema_for_getall
    @_action_for_getall
    def get_all(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

or with `lambda`:

```
class DynamicCrud(viewsets.ViewSet):
    @(lambda method:
        lambda self, *args, **kwargs:
            swagger_auto_schema(
                operation_summary=f'Get all {self.table_name}',
                responses={200: serializer_class(many=True)}
            )(method)(self, *args, **kwargs)
    )
    @(lambda method:
        lambda self, *args, **kwargs:
            action(
                detail=False,
                methods=['get'],
                url_path='getall',
                url_name=f'{self.table_name}_getall'
            )(method)(self, *args, **kwargs)
    )
    def get_all(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

How could I forget basic of OOP, The solution is quite simple. I should not send back data to parent class as references. instead I inherit my function to child class and run decorator there where there is references data I need in the child class python file.

```
table_data = [
{
    'serializer_class': serializer.TblMCategories_serializer,
    'model_class': models.TblMCategories,
    'table_name': 'category'
},
# rest my table references data
]

class TblMCategories(dynamic_crud_viewset.DynamicCrud):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(
        serializer_class=table_data[0]['serializer_class'],
        model_class=table_data[0]['model_class'],
        table_name=table_data[0]['table_name']
    )

#run decorator in child class
@swagger_auto_schema(
    operation_summary=f'Get {table_data[0]["table_name"]} by ID',
    responses={200: serializer.TblMCategories_serializer()}
)
@action(detail=True, methods=['get'], url_path='getbyid',url_name=f'{table_data[0]["table_name"]}_getbyid')
def get_all(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().get_all(request, *args, **kwargs)
```